# Issue updating user data in coredata

Tags: swift, core-data

In my project I have two view controller “PatientListViewController” and  “PatientsEditViewController”. In  “PatientListViewController” I am showing all the patient list. When I am going to “PatientsEditViewController” I am trying to update information. After updating when I am coming back to “PatientListViewController”. The previous data is showing but not the updated patient info.

My PatientListViewController is-

```
class PatientListViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private var coreData = CoreDataStack()
    private var patientList = [Patient]()
    private var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext?
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        checkDataStore()
        
    }
    
    
    private func checkDataStore() {
        managedObjectContext = coreData.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let sortByName = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
        let sortDescriptors = [ sortByName]
        
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Patient> = Patient.fetchRequest()
        request.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
        
        do {
            let count = try managedObjectContext!.count(for: request)
            
            if count != 0 {
                let patients = try managedObjectContext!.fetch(request)
                patientList = patients
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
                
            }
        }
        catch {
            fatalError("Error getting student count")
        }
        
    }
}
```

My PatientsEditViewController is-

```
class PatientsEditViewController: UIViewController {

       private var coreData = CoreDataStack()
       private var patientList = [Patient]()
       private var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext?


 @IBAction func savePatientBtnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        updateCoredata { (updated) in
            if updated{
               self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            }
        }
    }

private func updateCoredata(completion: (Bool) -> Void){
         do {
                    
                    if patientList.count != 0 { // Atleast one was returned
                        
                        // In my case, I only updated the first item in results
                        guard let firstName = firstName_TextFiled.text,
                            let lastName = lastName_TextFiled.text,
                            let email = email_TextField.text,
                            let zip = zipCode_TextField.text,
                            let phone = phone_TextField.text,
                            let gender = gender_TextField.text,
                            let location = location_TextField.text
                            else {
                                return
                        }
                        
                        let name = firstName.capitalized + " " + lastName.capitalized
                        
                        patientList[0].setValue(name, forKey: "name")
                        patientList[0].setValue(email, forKey: "email")
                        patientList[0].setValue("password", forKey: "password")
                        patientList[0].setValue(gender, forKey: "gender")
                        patientList[0].setValue(phone, forKey: "phone")
                        patientList[0].setValue(zip, forKey: "zip")
                        patientList[0].setValue(location, forKey: "deliveryLocation")
                        
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("Fetch Failed: \(error)")
                    completion(false)
                }
                
                do {
                  
                    try managedObjectContext!.save()
                    completion(true)
                    
                }
                catch {
                    print("Saving Core Data Failed: \(error)")
                    completion(false)
                }
            }
}
```

Please tell me where i am doing wrong.

Comment: How do you know the data gets updated and saved? Did you try to debug this?

Comment: yes the data is saved. Because if i am going again to the "PatientsEditViewController", the data is showing there. Or if i am trying to run the application again, then the updated data is also showing in  "PatientListViewController".

Comment: One option is to use a NSFetchedResultsController instead for better handling of updates but it involves a bit more work

Comment: hi @JoakimDanielson i have tried  "NSFetchedResultsController". But why  the delegate methods  of NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate are not calling  ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this inside your PatientListViewController.

```
@IBAction func unwindToViewControllerA(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
   }
```

and also call tableView.reloadData() inside your viewWillAppear().

Comment: still it is not working. If i am running the app the updated data is coming.